# Elasticsearch + django: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have browsed for this error on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but nothing helps.

I have installed django-elasticsearch-dsl and added it to my INSTALLED_APPS. In my settings, I have:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL={
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}
```

Next, I have a 'documents.py' file where the logic for Elastic search resides.
When I try running **python manage.py search_index --rebuild**, I get this error:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html

I don't know if I understand correctly how to run the ES server. I have tried to run the local server on port 9200 but the issue persists.

Comment: Please attach your `documents.py` to your question.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I thought that installing elasticsearch with pip was enough, but I had to actually download the full application, install, and run it, and then it all worked.